# Updating React State

Tags: javascript, reactjs, parent-child, use-state

I am having trouble updating the state in the `Parent` component. I have React functional components with this structure:

```
//parent.js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Child from './child.js';

const Parent = () => {

    const [ value, setValue ] = useState([
       {name:['tutorial', 1, 'langkah'], value:"ABC"},
       {name:['tutorial', 2, 'langkah'], value:"DEF"},
       {name:['tutorial', 3, 'langkah'], value:"GHI"}
    ]);

    const deleteY = (data) => {
        const newValue = value.filter(obj => !obj.name.includes(data));
        setValue(newValue);
    }

    return (

    <Child deleteX={deleteY} />

    )

}
export default Parent;
```

...and a Child component:

```
//child.js
import React from 'react';
import Button from 'antd/es/button'; //edited

const Child = ({deleteX}) => {

    let x = 1;

    return (
        <Button onClick={() => deleteX(x)}>Click Me!</Button>
    )

}
export default Child;
```

With this setup, I can't delete that particular array in the state `value` by clicking on the 'Click Me!' button. Why is this happening? Is there something that I missed?

***Edit**: I forgot to put the import statement for the `Button` in the `child.js` code example, and the `const newValue`. This isn't the source of the problem as I have the proper import and variable declaration in the original file.*

Comment: <Button is a custom component or is that a typo?

Comment: And whats the result, did you attempt to debug it?

Comment: You have declared let newValue right?

Comment: Please note that a state update that depends on the previous state should provide a callback that gets the previous state, i.e.  `const deleteY = (data) => { setValue(prevValue => prevValue.filter(obj => !obj.name.includes(data)));}`

In your case it's fine but it's a good practice to follow in case somebody quickly press your button twice.
See https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates

Comment: @TusharShahi yes

Comment: @NikitaMazur the state remains unchanged. tried to console.log the state.

Comment: Have you tried replacing `<Button>` with `<button>`? @Mustakim's answer shows everything working with `<button>`.

Comment: That was a red herring. It works with ant design <Button> as well.

Answer (score -1):

You missed the `button` tag. here is code sandbox working URL

[You working example](https://codesandbox.io/embed/vigilant-breeze-0ny0v?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

click the button and see the console.